# How can i call a function without click button ? (visual studio c# 2017)

Tags: c#, winforms

How can i call a function without click button ?

When i opened a form, i want to run a function without click any button.

How i can run function?

```
int sayfa = 1;
int kapasite = 20;


        public Form2()
        {

            InitializeComponent();

        }


        private void sayfayi_goster(int Sayfa, int Kapasite)
        {
            textBox6.Text = Sayfa.ToString() + "/" + Kapasite.ToString();
        }

        sayfayi.goster(sayfa,kapasite); // its not working !!!
```

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with the development environment "Visual Studio", but with the UI technology "Windows Forms". I adjusted your tags accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the call in a form event like `Shown` or `Load`.

Go to the Events Tab in the Properties Editor of the Visual Studio Designer.

Double click on `Shown` or `Load` and add the call you want.

```
private void Form2_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  sayfayi.goster(sayfa, kapasite);
}
```

Depending of what you want to do you can use the constructor or Load event.

Here is the chain of calls:

1. Constructor : prefered place to instantiate objects and initialize UI instances.
2. Load : prefered place to create and initialize non designer UI controls or complete them like populating combobox or dataset.
3. Activated : prefered place to do things *each time* the form is activated and get focus.
4. Shown : prefered place to do things after the form is showned like open another form or show an info box.

The difference between using constructor, load or shown is mainly to have a clean code design and a smooth UI behavior.

There is no real difference between putting code in the constructor or in the load, but if a non catched exception occurs in the constructor it is more serious than in the load because the reference is not created.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/order-of-events-in-windows-forms